# JPA @ElementCollection doesn't create columns

Tags: java, jpa, orm

in my application I have an `@Entity` that *embeds* a `Request` class, that contains an `Issue` property and a list of `Attachment`s.
An `Attachment` is also an `Issue`.
An `Issue` have `Code` property with a `number` and a `year`, so I have:

```
@Embeddable
public class Code{
     private Long number;
     private Integer year;
}

@Embeddable
public class Issue{
    private Code code;
}

@Embeddable
public class Attachment extends Issue{
     @ManyToOne
     private Category category;
}

@Embeddable
public class Request{
    @AttributeOverrides(value={
        @AttributeOverride(name="code.year", column=@Column(name="issue_year")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="code.number", column=@Column(name="issue_number")),
    })
    private Issue issue;

    @AttributeOverrides(value={
        @AttributeOverride(name="code.year", column=@Column(name="attachment_year")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="code.number", column=@Column(name="attachment_number")),
    })
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name="attachments")
    private List<Attachment> attachments;
}
```

Now the problem is that in the generated tables I have the `attachments` table but without the `attachment_year` and `attachment_number` columns!

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should design Issue and Attachment as entities. At some point, your app will probably need to reference, create, remove, display, modify issues and attachments. Being able to reference them uniquely by ID and retrieve them via queries will be necessary.

Comment: No, they are *Value Object* (as DDD concept) they have means for other applications in the ecosystem but for me they are just values, I don't care about their identity

Comment: Are the other columns of the table `attachements` correctly generated ? What JPA provider do you use? Have you tried to upgrade/downgrade it?